# What is the reaction mechanism for this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons

Is it Polar unsymmetrical bond breaking (heterolytic) mechanism?

[image: Reaction Mechanism]

Comment: Google "free radical halogenation".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is halogenation by free radical mechanism. In UV radiations halogen gas produces two halogen free radical which can cause allylic substitutions

[image]!

Comment: Thank you. Can you please draw the entire reaction mechanism of this by hand ? Its hard to understand without equation and arrow heads

Comment: (@Abhishek) This mechanism is not correct. The C–X bond is (primarily) formed via a propagation step $\ce{R^. + X–X -> R–X + X^.}$, not a termination step $\ce{R^. + X^. -> RX}$. The "influence of $\ce{X^.}$" is also not an appropriate way to describe the hydrogen atom abstraction $\ce{R–H + X^. -> R^. + H–X}$.